# Laravel caching with Redis - what does this key mean?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

We're using Redis caching with Laravel. Sometimes we store objects with keys such as: 
Product-4151-Details
Category-4123-Products

When we run `redis-cli keys *` we get keys such as the following:

> laravel:af6e03943c3803e85bbf455fa26:Category-4123-Products
>   laravel:af6e03943c3803e85bbf455fa26:Product-4151-Details

We have thousands of these keys (we cache a lot), and these hashes are often duplicated multiple times. What are these hashes, what do they mean, and why are they sometimes duplicated? (When I refer to the hashes I'm referring to this part of the key: **af6e03943c3803e85bbf455fa26**).  The laravel portion is the cache prefix we have set up in our cache.php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is used as part of the tagging feature for caching.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisTaggedCache.php

The hash is a unique namespace that changes when any of the tags are flushed.

Comment: Thank you. That actually makes sense.